# Use graphical analysis to solve a parameterised LP problem

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research, constraints, parametrization

[image]

---

1. For $c < 0$, we have no feasible solutions and hence no optimal solutions.
2. For $c=0$, our only feasible solution is $z=0$ obtained by $(0,0)$.
3. For $c > 0$, well...

I [graphed the constraints](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2By%20%3C%3D%2014,%20x%2B3y%20%3C%3D%2012,%20y%20%3C%3D%203,%20x%20%3D%3E%200,%20y%20%3D%3E%200) besides $x_1 + x_2 = c$ and came up with a feasible region with corner points $(0,0), (0,3), (3,3), (6,2), (7,0)$.

1. For $c \in (0,3]$, it looks like [we have a triangle for a feasible region](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2By%20%3C%3D%2014,%20x%2B3y%20%3C%3D%2012,%20y%20%3C%3D%203,%20x%20%3D%3E%200,%20y%20%3D%3E%200,%20x%2By%20%3C%3D3) and so need only inspect $(0,0), (c,0), (0,c)$
2. [For $c=4$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2By%20%3C%3D%2014,%20x%2B3y%20%3C%3D%2012,%20y%20%3C%3D%203,%20x%20%3D%3E%200,%20y%20%3D%3E%200,%20x%2By%20%3C%3D4), we inspect $(0,0), (4,0), (0,3), (1,3)$
3. [For $c=5$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2By%20%3C%3D%2014,%20x%2B3y%20%3C%3D%2012,%20y%20%3C%3D%203,%20x%20%3D%3E%200,%20y%20%3D%3E%200,%20x%2By%20%3C%3D5), we inspect $(0,0), (5,0), (0,3), (2,3)$
4. [For $c=6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2By%20%3C%3D%2014,%20x%2B3y%20%3C%3D%2012,%20y%20%3C%3D%203,%20x%20%3D%3E%200,%20y%20%3D%3E%200,%20x%2By%20%3C%3D6), we inspect $(0,0), (6,0), (0,3), (3,3)$
5. Generalising: For $c \in \color{red}{[}3,6]$, we inspect $(0,0), (c,0), (0,3), (c-3,3)$ where for $\color{red}{c=3}$, $(0,3) = (c-3,3)$
6. [For $c=7$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2By%20%3C%3D%2014,%20x%2B3y%20%3C%3D%2012,%20y%20%3C%3D%203,%20x%20%3D%3E%200,%20y%20%3D%3E%200,%20x%2By%20%3C%3D7), we inspect $(0,0), (7,0), (0,3), (3,3)$ and the intersection between $x_1+x_2=c=7$ and $x_1+3x_2=12$ which is $(9/2,5/2)$
7. Generalising: For $c \in (6,7]$, we inspect $(0,0), (c,0), (0,3), (3,3)$ and the intersection between $x_1+x_2=c$ and $x_1+3x_2=12$ which is $(-6+3c/2,6-c/2)$
8. [For $c = 7.5$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2By%20%3C%3D%2014,%20x%2B3y%20%3C%3D%2012,%20y%20%3C%3D%203,%20x%20%3D%3E%200,%20y%20%3D%3E%200,%20x%2By%20%3C%3D7.5), we inspect $(0,0), (7,0), (0,3), (3,3)$, the intersection between $x_1+x_2=c=7.5$ and $x_1+3x_2=12$ which is $(5.25,2.25)$ and the intersection between $x_1+x_2=c=7.5$ and $2x_1+x_2=14$ which is $(6.5,1)$
9. Generalising: For $c \in (7,8]$, we inspect, we inspect $(0,0), (7,0), (0,3), (3,3)$, the intersection between $x_1+x_2=c$ and $x_1+3x_2=12$ which is $(-6+3c/2,6-c/2)$ and the intersection between $x_1+x_2=c$ and $2x_1+x_2=14$ which is $(14-c,2c-14)$
10. For $c=8$, the constraint $x_1+x_2 \le c = 8$ is redundant as can be seen here:

[With $x_1+x_2 \le c = 8$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2By%20%3C%3D%2014,%20x%2B3y%20%3C%3D%2012,%20y%20%3C%3D%203,%20x%20%3D%3E%200,%20y%20%3D%3E%200,%20x%2By%20%3C%3D8).

[Without $x_1+x_2 \le c = 8$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2By%20%3C%3D%2014,%20x%2B3y%20%3C%3D%2012,%20y%20%3C%3D%203,%20x%20%3D%3E%200,%20y%20%3D%3E%200).

11. Generalising: For $c\ge8$, the constraint $x_1+x_2 \le c$ is redundant.

---

Is that right?

---

From Chapter 2 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Comment: Looks correct. Are you going to give the maximum value for $z$ in each of the cases you have outlined?

Comment: @tomi probably not. It's just algebra right? I can give you accepted answer if you want